# Template magic for creating a SerializerManager

Tags: c++, templates

I am creating an application that is editing data and then needs to be store it in various formats. The problem is that the application is built with a plugin architecture
in mind so I don't know which formats or which objects that needs to be stored beforehand.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a SerializeManager where you can register dynamically which formats that is supported.

The goal is to be able to create an object and then specify which formats that is supported with template specializations.
Example:

```
template<typename Type, typename Format>
void serialize(const Type& type, const Format& format)
{
}

class IFormat
{
public:
    virtual ~IFormat(){} 
};

class XmlFormat : public IFormat
{

};

class BinaryFormat : public IFormat
{

};

class MyDataToStore
{
public:
    int m_data1; //Data to store
    string m_data2; //Data to store
};

template<>
void serialize(const MyDataToStore& type, const XmlFormat& format)
{
    //Serialization code goes here
}
```

My goal now is to create a SerializeManager that manages all formats and calls the correct specialization. I would like it to work something like this:

```
int main()
{
    SerializeManager man;
    man.RegisterFormat(".xml", std::shared_ptr<IFormat>(new XmlFormat())); // Where .xml is a key

    MyDataToStore obj;

    man.Store<MyDataToStore>(".xml", obj); //where .xml is a key
}
```

The goal is to end up in the MyDataToStore, Xml specialization above without having to specify the format as a template argument in the Store function. Is this even possible? I have tried having a pure virtual function in the IFormat class that calls the serialize function in the sub classes but since virtual functions cant use templates i loose the MyDataToStore and default function is called.

Regards!

EDIT:

If someone wonders I settled with the following solution. I skipped my desire to only having to specify a extension when serializing/deserializing. This is my result.

```
#include <string>

template<typename Formatter, typename Type>
void serialize(Formatter& format, Type& type)
{
static_assert(false, "No known serializer function found");
}

template<typename Formatter, typename Type>
void deserialize(Formatter& format, Type& type)
{
static_assert(false, "No known deserializer function found");
}

class SerializeManager
{
public:
    SerializeManager(){}
    virtual ~SerializeManager(){}

    template<typename Type, typename Formatter>
    bool Serialize(std::string filepath, Type & t)
    {
        Formatter format(filepath);
        format.setManager(this);
        serialize<Formatter, Type>(format, t);
        return true;
    }

    template<typename Type, typename Formatter>
    bool Serialize(Formatter& format, Type& t)
    {
        serialize(format, t);
        return true;
    }

    template<typename Type, typename Formatter>
    bool Deserialize(std::string filepath, Type & t)
    {
        Formatter format(filepath);
        format.setManager(this);
        deserialize<Formatter, Type>(format, t);
        return true;
    }

    template<typename Type, typename Formatter>
    bool Deserialize(Formatter& format, Type& t)
    {
        deserialize(format, t);
        return true;
    }


private:

};

class FormatterBase
{
public:
    void setManager(SerializeManager* man)
    {
        m_manager = man;
    }

    SerializeManager* getManager()
    {
        return m_manager;
    }

private:
    SerializeManager* m_manager;
};
```

The static_assert help with rising a compiler error if no specialized function is found. Seems to work well. Usage:

```
#include "SerializeManager.h"

struct Human
{
    template<typename T, typename S>
    friend void serialize(T& t, S& s);

    template<typename T, typename S>
    friend void deserialize(T& t, S& s);

    Human(int age, std::string name) : m_age(age), m_name(name){}

private:

    int m_age;
    std::string m_name;
};

class XmlSerializer : public FormatterBase
{
public:
XmlSerializer(std::string filepath){}

void NewNode(std::string name){}
};

template<>
void serialize(XmlSerializer& serial, Human& human)
{
    //Do the serialization
}

int main()
{
    SerializeManager man;
    Human åke(15, "Åke");
    man.Serialize<Human, XmlSerializer>("file.xml", åke);
}
```

Comment: Usually there's not really _magic_ in templates, though I'm seeing fairies, trolls, unicorns and such stuff all day long ;) ...

Comment: But the word magic make the whole task seem so much more exiting don't you think?

Comment: Take a look at `boost::serialize`.

Comment: boost::serialize looks quite suitable. Will look into it! Thinx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're running before you can walk here.

What you need is an intermediate format.  It can be binary, it can be a tree of name/value pairs, it doesn't matter.  What *matters* is that everything can serialize to this intermediate format.

Then, it is a simple (ha!) case of writing serializers to and from this intermediate format.  Xml, Json, Binary, or whatever other esoteric format you can come up with.

The key is the *well known and well defined* intermediate layer.  Once you have that, it doesn't really matter what happens at the other end.

Comment: **... well known and well defined ...** @user3574485: See? No _magic_ here.

Comment: Whats the fun in walking? :) To be honest I do this little project more for the fun of testing new approaches than for the project itself. I do more straight forward stuff at work so this is playtime :)

Comment: @user3574485, template meta-programming - whilst fun (I agree!) isn't there to solve esoteric problems that shouldn't be resolved in this manner.  Template meta-programming is great, but it is not suited to this task :)

Comment: Its just that it would have been such a beautiful solution :) Just having to create the specialization and then by magic ( I still believe in magic... ) it would have been called. :)